# Derivative of a logarithm from first principles

Tags: calculus

The usual example where learning about the derivative is obtaining it for $f(x)=x^2$ from first principles (see [this](http://www.intmath.com/differentiation/3-derivative-first-principles.php) for example).

I am stumped on how use first principles to obtain the derivative of a natural logarithm.  We need:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln x}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{h}{x})}{h}$$

Now I am stuck.  Of course I know that Taylor expansion around very small $x$ of $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\ldots$, but that's not something one is supposed to know when learning first principles of differentiation.  Is there something clever that I am missing?

Comment: The usual way, of course, is to take $\exp(\log(x))$ and differentiate it using the chain rule. I don't know of a more first-principlesy way.
To use the Taylor series would be to assume the result, since it is built from the derivative of $\log$.

Comment: It depends on what your _definition_ of the logarithm is. In some developments you simply define $\log x = \int_1^x\frac1t\, dt$, in which case the derivative is directly by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @PatrickStevens But that's not from first principles. Besides, I learnt what the derivative of $e^x$ is through the chain rule and the derivative of $\ln x$, not the other way around...

Comment: @5xum, that also depends on the definition of $\exp$. In my course, it was defined as a power series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should know that
$$\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\log(1+k)}{k}=1$$
Then, calling $k= \frac hx$, you get
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(1+\frac hx)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(1+\frac hx)}{x\frac hx} = 1 \cdot  \frac{1}{x}= \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I may be being obtuse, but how do we know that $\lim \frac{\log(1+k)}{k} = 1$ without knowing the derivative of $\log$?

Comment: Take $\log$ to the fundamental limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac 1x} = e$$ which is a (almost) direct consequence of definition of $e$: $$e= \lim_{t \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac 1t \right)^t$$

Answer (score 0):

If $w=\log x$ then $e^w = x$.

$$\frac {\Bbb d(\Bbb e^w)} {\Bbb dx} = 1 \implies
\frac {\Bbb d(\Bbb e^w)} {dw} \frac {\Bbb dw} {\Bbb dx} = 1 \implies
\Bbb e^w \frac {\Bbb dw} {\Bbb dx} = 1 \implies
\frac {\Bbb dw} {\Bbb dx} = \frac 1 {\Bbb e^w} = \frac 1 x \implies
\frac {\Bbb d(\log x)} {\Bbb dx} = \frac 1 x .$$

Comment: (The $\mathbb d$ and $\mathbb e$ are over the top.)

Comment: Thanks - that's much nicer

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln (x+h) - \ln x}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \ln \left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right) \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \frac{h}{x} \ln \left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{h}} \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \ln e \\ &= \frac{1}{x}. \end{align}