# Find, from the first principle, the derivative of $\textrm {ln} x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find, from the first principle, the derivative of $\ln x$.

My Attempt:
\begin{align}f(x)&=\ln (x)\\
f(x+\Delta x)&= \ln (x+\Delta x)\end{align}
Now, by formula:
\begin{align}f'(x)&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {f(x+ \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\ln(x+\Delta x) -\ln(x)}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\ln\left(\dfrac {x+\Delta x}{x}\right)}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {1}{\Delta x} \ln \left(1+\dfrac {\Delta x}{x}\right)\end{align}

How do.I proceed further?

Comment: What is the definition of $\ln$ in use?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Natural log.

Comment: That much is clear, but how is it defined? as the inverse of $\exp$? As $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$? Something else?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404805/derivative-of-a-logarithm-from-first-principles

Comment: remember for small small 'x' we have that $ ln(1+x) \to x $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the fact that $e^{\ln x} = x$ then call

$$
f(x) = \ln x
$$

Such that

$$
e^{f(x)} = e^{\ln x} = x
$$

and

$$
\frac{de^{f(x)}}{dx} = e^{f(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx} = 1 = x\frac{d\ln x}{dx}
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{d\ln x}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}
$$